# for loop in Django for custom n number of times

Tags: python, django

I want to run for loop based on the number of each individual model entry, I have a **testimonial** model and one of its field is *ratings*(and integer field) I want to run a **for-loop** for n times, where **n=ratings value** for that particular entry.

for ex:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here ratings = 4 I want to run for-loop for 4 times so that I can show 4 stars in the testimonial section.

I tried doing this:(which of course is the wrong method, mentioning just for sake demonstration of what I want)

```
          <div>
            {% for _ in range({{testimonial.ratings}}) %}
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

the models.py looks something like this:

```
class Testimonials(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="testimonials_photo/", null=True, verbose_name='Client Photo', blank=True)
    ratings = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="rating")
    pt_messsage = models.TextField(verbose_name="Message")
    pt_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Patient Name", max_length=200)
    client_profession = models.CharField(verbose_name="Patient Profession", max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pt_name
```

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: @Jayant Nigam answered edit the picture, without it it's not exactly clear what is needed.